# Why does the XCode Output Window sometimes log in bold other times in plain?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it to do with threads?  Or the hardware its being run on?

[image: bold]

[image: plain]

Comment: the size of the font differs.

Comment: in XCode 4.3, it is not bold.. whereas it was bold before.. I am so used to the bold logs.. Is there a way to get the bold logs back?

Answer (score 3):

The GDB debugger prints to the console using a bold font whereas the new LLDB debugger (the default one in Xcode 4.x) uses an undecorated font.

Comment: Great, I knew there must be a reason. Do you know this for a fact? do you have a source?

Comment: i think oscahie concludes this by observation.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that :

- Bold is input and plain is output for the debugger.
- Bold is output and plain is input for the 'Executable console'.

Im not sure this is 100% consistant with what Iv seen previously, but its what the preferences suggests. (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> `->` fonts and colors -> console).

Screenshot from Xcode 4.5:

[image: Prefs]